# Google Drive Sync run program aftersync

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there anyway on the google drive program to set some program to run after the sync?
Everytime it syncs it runs a script or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible. Its not in its configuration and does not have any documented way to do it.

Comment: For windows, win32 has an api to watch changes on a given directory. I suppose other OSs have something similar. You can use that to wait until you find it has stabilized (ie finished sync) and make your backup.